# How to take upvotes for the answer in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am developing website for simple question and answer forum. I want to get upvotes for an answer.

**models.py**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    ans = models.TextField()
    img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answer')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ques = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ans

class Upvote(models.Model):
    upvote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    upvote_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='upvote')
    upvoted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #ques = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='upvote')
    ans = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='upvote')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.upvote_by
```

**views.py**

I can get upvotes for an answer like below

```
 answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, pk=1)
 upvotes = Upvote.objects.filter(ans=answer)
```

How to take upvotes from answer object ? Is it possible please correct me if i am wrong. Something like below,

```
answer.upvote_set
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You define a `related_name='upvote'` so that would be `answer.upvote.filter(...)`

Comment: one answer can have mulitple upvotes then how to pass answer object to html template ? I need to access upvote from answer  object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this field you show in your models:

```
class Upvote(models.Model):
    # ... other code ...
    ans = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='upvote')
    # ... other code ...
```

You can access the upvotes of an answer like this

```
answer_instance.upvote.all()
```

---

If you change your field definition to this (removing `related_name`):

```
ans = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
```

you should be able to use the code you asked about:

```
answer_instance.upvote_set.all()
```